Ошибка ValueError: not enough values to unpack
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # открываем папку с изображениями
    _, path = argv
    # перечисляем изображения в папке
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.jpg"))
    # создаём список возможных аугментаций
    augmentation_types = {0: "deblur", 1: "gaus_blur", 2: "sp_noise", 3: "brightness", 4: "contrast"}


Заголовок вопроса должен быть кратким и по существу. трейс ошибки нужно прикладывать полностью. строку №90 нам самим посчитать и найти?

исправил, но проблема ещё осталась)

Звездочку потеряли: _, path = *argv. Так элементы из списка argv распакуются в _ и path.

Возможно надо так:
path = argv[1]

Если да, то лучше ещё добавить:
if (len(argv) < 2):
    print("Input path in argv!")
    exit()
path = argv[1]


получилось ещё 2 ошибки)
Traceback (most recent call last): line 92, in 
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.jpg"))
и в другой части кода:
path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

@Nikita Возможно исправил
